# elasticsearch bulk delete request success, but not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform bulk delete request using `BulkProcessor`,with init code as follows:

```
BulkProcessor bulkProcessor = BulkProcessor.builder(client, new BulkProcessor.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void beforeBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request) {
                log.warn("executionId:" + executionId + " bulk start => numberOfActions:" + request.numberOfActions() + " size:" + request.estimatedSizeInBytes());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, BulkResponse response) {
                log.warn("executionId:" + executionId + " bulk end => tookInMillis:" + response.getTookInMillis());
                log.warn("executionId:" + executionId + " bulk end => response:" + JSON.toJSONString(response));
            }

            @Override
            public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, Throwable failure) {
                log.warn("executionId:" + executionId + " bulk executed occur error:", failure);
            }
        }).setBulkActions(500).setBulkSize(new ByteSizeValue(14, ByteSizeUnit.MB)).setConcurrentRequests(1).build(); 

//search ids to delete
List<String> ids = searchByCondition(index,type,start,end);     //ids.size() = 500
//call bulk
    for(String id : ids){
        DeleteRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest(index, type, id);
        bulkProcessor.add(deleteRequest);
    }
```

After request,none record in es is deleted. And I got the process result log as follows:

```
{  
   "context":{  
      "empty":true
   },
   "contextEmpty":true,
   "headers":[  

   ],
   "items":[  
      {  
         "failed":false,
         "id":"14720103",
         "index":"my_index",
         "itemId":483,
         "opType":"delete",
         "response":{  
            "context":{  
               "$ref":"$.context"
            },
            "contextEmpty":true,
            "found":false,
            "headers":[  

            ],
            "id":"14720103",
            "index":"my_index",
            "shardInfo":{  
               "failed":0,
               "failures":[  

               ],
               "successful":1,
               "total":1
            },
            "type":"my_type",
            "version":1
         },
         "type":"my_type",
         "version":1
      },
      {  
         "failed":false,
         "id":"14720827",
         "index":"my_index",
         "itemId":484,
         "opType":"delete",
         "response":{  
            "context":{  
               "$ref":"$.context"
            },
            "contextEmpty":true,
            "found":false,
            "headers":[  

            ],
            "id":"14720827",
            "index":"my_index",
            "shardInfo":{  
               "failed":0,
               "failures":[  

               ],
               "successful":1,
               "total":1
            },
            "type":"my_type",
            "version":1
         },
         "type":"my_type",
         "version":1
      },
      {  
         "failed":false,
         "id":"14720898",
         "index":"my_index",
         "itemId":499,
         "opType":"delete",
         "response":{  
            "context":{  
               "$ref":"$.context"
            },
            "contextEmpty":true,
            "found":false,
            "headers":[  

            ],
            "id":"14720898",
            "index":"my_index",
            "shardInfo":{  
               "failed":0,
               "failures":[  

               ],
               "successful":1,
               "total":1
            },
            "type":"my_type",
            "version":1
         },
         "type":"my_type",
         "version":1
      }
   ],
   "took":{  
      "days":0,
      "daysFrac":5.358796296296296E-6,
      "hours":0,
      "hoursFrac":1.286111111111111E-4,
      "micros":463000,
      "microsFrac":463000.0,
      "millis":463,
      "millisFrac":463.0,
      "minutes":0,
      "minutesFrac":0.007716666666666667,
      "nanos":463000000,
      "seconds":0,
      "secondsFrac":0.463
   },
   "tookInMillis":463
}
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I shortened the response log , the actual response item size is 500, the same as request ids size.

Comment: Are you using close or awaitClose for closing the bulk processor

Comment: No, I didn't close the processor.

Comment: awaitClose the bulk processor and see whether it deletes the records

Comment: I tried but it still didn't work.
`bulkProcessor.awaitClose(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: If you are using alias names for index, try using the original name instead of alias name.

Comment: The index name i used was the original name

Comment: I'm confused why the `response` in each `item` tells `"found":false` ,while the document actually exits in elasticsearch server?

Comment: By 'none record in es is deleted' you mean you can still find it with a search? Are you by any chance confusing the ids? Make sure the delete request contains the value of the '_id' field of the object in elasticsearch.